# Lost access to IP restricted server

Tags: permissions, ip, restrictions

So we have a server that has IP restrictions set for SSH, cPanel..etc and our static IP has been recently changed before we could update the IP restrictions meaning we have lost access. The support provided by the host is extremely s**t. Is there anything we can do to regain access?

Any way I can spoof our current IP to match the old?

Answer (score 1):

Spoofing is useless - responses from server will never reach you back. You have several ways you can do:

- Ask your ISP to return you your old IP for a moment
- If you have physical access to server, go to datacenter and change firewall from terminal
- If it is virtual server, you have to ask your provider to reset your firewall. They can do it pretty easy, but probably will need some verification. If they don't want to do it, you definitelly should change your provider ASAP.

You should set up VPN on your server and restrict SSH to VPN only. Sometimes you will have to manage your server when you will be out of office and you will need access.